# How to make Nimsoft run a script when an alert is trapped?

Tags: monitoring

We'd like configure Nimsoft Alert Server [NAS] to run a script that collects additional data from the servers which trigger an alert.

For example: when server XYZ trips an alert for CPU utilization, the NAS should run go back and run a script against server XYZ to collect additional data like what applications where running.

I have a basic powershell script that collects the desired data, the problem here is that the vendor my company hired to configure Nimsoft is telling me that the script must be stored locally on each server and can not be stored centrally. Additionally they're tell me that at best Nimsoft can only go and execute my script and report the scripts output on a schedule, not when an alert is trapped. This seems like BS, so I'm here looking for clarification.

Is it possible to configure Nimsoft to execute powershell scripts that may be stored and executed from the NAS, when an alert is trapped?

Comment: No solution but I had to work with Nimsoft once and my experience wasn't the best. I'm truly sorry for having to work with this product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to have an Auto-Operator Profile in the NAS match on the alarm and run a lua script, and that lua script can in turn invoke powershell (Shell.Execute should work I think?). This would require powershell to be configured for remote execution.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer provided me enough product buzzwords to locate this in the manual. Which is exactly what I needed.